# Find quotient group $GL(n, \mathbb{C})/H$, where $H$ is a group of invertible matrices $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ with $det \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Find quotient (factor) group $GL(n, \mathbb{C})/H$, where $H$ is a group of invertible matrices $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ with $det \in \mathbb{R}$.

I suppose, the theorem that for any group homomorphism $f: G \to T$ and its kernel $K$ there is always an isomorphism $G/K \to im(f)$ - is of use here, but I couldn't devise the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following : Given a surjective homomorphism $f:G\to G'$ between two groups, and a normal subgroup $H'<G'$, consider the map
$$
G \to G'/H' \text{ given by } a \mapsto f(a)H'
$$
Show that this is a surjective homomorphism which kernel $f^{-1}(H')$.

Edit: To complete the proof, let $G = GL_n(\mathbb{C}), G' = \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $f$ be the determinant map. Let $H' = \mathbb{R}^{\times} \triangleleft G'$, then by definition
$$
H = f^{-1}(H')
$$
Hence by the above statement and the first isomorphism theorem,
$$
G/H \cong G'/H' = \mathbb{C}^{\times}/\mathbb{R}^{\times}
$$
Now you can use polar coordinates to recover the right hand side as something familiar.

Comment: At a factor group $B/V$, the equivalence class of an identity element of group $B$ is an identity element of the factor group (namely, $V$), so of course in this case the kernel (the preimage of an identity element) of $f$ is $f^{-1}(H')$.
But how will it help me at finding the exact group isomorphic to $G/H$, which was the question?

Comment: It turns out, $T/\{+1, -1\} \cong T$ with isomorphism $p: T \to T/\{+1, -1\}, p(x) = \left[\frac {arg(x)}{2} \right]$, where $[...]$ is equivalence class. So the isomorphism $\frac{c}{mod(c)}$ from $\mathbb{C}^\times$ to $T/\{+1, -1\}$ is good.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show the image of $\left[0,\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$ under $\theta\mapsto e^{i\theta}I$ is a transversal for $H$ in $GL(V)$.

Alternately: $f^{-1}(A)\to f^{-1}(B)\to B/A$ is exact ($f=\det$, $B=\Bbb C^\times,A=\Bbb R^\times$).